# Why am I getting access denied exception to get a secret when invoking my lambda function even though it has permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

When invoking a test for my lambda function in the lambda console I get:

> AccessDeniedException: User:
> arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/role-for-my-lambda-function/some-other-role
> is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on
> resource: MyKey

**role-for-my-lambda-function** is the role I've created and attached to the lamdba function. It contains  permission to get the secret value.

I don't know where **some-other-role** comes from though.

This is the policy:

```
        - Sid: 'accessSecret'
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - 'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue'
          Resource:
          - 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:secret:MyKey-yyyyy'
```

What is wrong and how should I fix it?

Comment: You can check the role associated with the Lambda in console. Go to Configuration -> Permissions -> Execution role. It should also show the resources it has permission to access under Resource summary

Comment: Yes, it shows that it has the correct permission.

Comment: Problem found and solved: the [secretsmanager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SecretsManager.html) was created in the wrong region.